# grid-column-end property is leaving an empty area

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to display the 3 last elements of a container in an horizontal line.
The first 2 taking up a fixed space and the last element taking all columns left.

I'm trying to achieve this result with a CSS Grid.

So far I've been able to do a working prototype when the grid is full (more than 3 elements).

But as you can see in the snippet below, if there's less than 3 elements, the last column end at the right at the grid but leaves a gap in the grid.

I have tried with specifying `grid-column: auto / -1;` instead of `grid-column-end` with no luck.

I am using Chrome but tested it on Firefox as well

**What might cause this gap and is there a good way to fix it using only CSS ?**

**EDIT :** Completed the scenario and added expected result

```css
.demo {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.demo>.demo {
  background-color: #fedcba;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.main>.column:last-child {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

.main>.column:nth-last-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">1</div>
  <div class="demo column">2</div>
  <div class="demo column">3</div>
  <div class="demo column">4</div>
</div>
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">1</div>
  <div class="demo column">2</div>
  <div class="demo column">3</div>
</div>
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">1</div>
  <div class="demo column">2</div>
</div>
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">1</div>
</div>
```

Excpected result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding items using this CSS.

```
.main > .column:nth-last-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

So you just need some additional adjustments:

1. Select first child and add `grid-column-start: 1;` using

   ```
   .main > .column:first-child {
     grid-column-start: 1;
   }
   ```
2. Select second child when it's sibling of first visible child and 
   add `grid-column-start: 2;` using

   ```
   .main > .column:not(:nth-last-child(n+4)) + .column:nth-child(2) {
     grid-column-start: 2;
   }
   ```

Result:

```css
.demo {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.demo > .demo {
  background-color: #fedcba;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.main > .column:first-child {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.main > .column:not(:nth-last-child(n+4)) + .column:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.main > .column:last-child {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

.main > .column:nth-last-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">1</div>
  <div class="demo column">2</div>
  <div class="demo column">3</div>
  <div class="demo column">4</div>
</div>
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">1</div>
  <div class="demo column">2</div>
  <div class="demo column">3</div>
</div>
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">1</div>
  <div class="demo column">2</div>
</div>
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is to make the second cell colapse if there is no content for it.

You can achieve it with

```
grid-template-columns: 100px auto 1fr;
```

```css
.demo {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.demo>.demo {
  background-color: #fedcba;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.main>.column:last-child {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

.main > .column:nth-last-child(n+2) {
  width: 100px;
}

.main>.column:nth-last-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">6</div>
  <div class="demo column">7</div>
</div>
<div class="demo main">
    <div class="demo column">5</div> 
  <div class="demo column">6</div>
  <div class="demo column">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to have the first elements with a fixed width.
With `auto` I'll have a column of varying width. either too small or too large depending on the content if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: You are right ... I have solved setting the width directly on the element

Answer (score 0):

With two grid items, there's a gap in the grid because you have the **last child** starting from the end of the container:

```
.main > .column:last-child {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

This may work well when there are at least three items in the container, because all cells are occupied. But with less than three, the `grid-column-end: -1` will shift the last item to the last column. ([Negative integers begin the count from the end of the container.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-placement-int))

You showed the problem with two items. The same problem exists even with one item:

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.main>.column:last-child {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

.demo {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.demo>.demo {
  background-color: #fedcba;
}

.main>.column:nth-last-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">7</div>
</div>
```

If you want the last child to occupy the second column as well, then instead of this:

```
grid-column-end: -1;
```

Try this:

```
grid-column: 2 / -1;
```

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.main>.column:last-child {
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
}

.demo {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.demo>.demo {
  background-color: #fedcba;
}


.main>.column:nth-last-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">6</div>
  <div class="demo column">7</div>
</div>
```

Or if you want the last item, when there are less than three, to occupy the second column then instead of using `:last-child`, use `nth-child()`, like this:

```
.main > .column:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.main>.column:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

.demo {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.demo>.demo {
  background-color: #fedcba;
}


.main>.column:nth-last-child(n+5) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo main">
  <div class="demo column">6</div>
  <div class="demo column">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only work if I have a fixed number of element or I want to display only the last 3 if they exists.
So I don't know from the start if it's the 2nd or 3rd element. Beside, with your solution, the column doesn't go to the end of the container.

Comment: Making it span to the end of the container is simple. I gave an example in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you edited the answer while I was commenting ^^. I cannot fix the starting column as I don't know if there is always the first element.  Maybe I wasn't clear in the question. There can be 1 to n elements and I want the 3 last displayed with the very last taking all the space remaining.

Comment: Consider posting a more complete example, so we can see the actual scenario. Your grid container creates only three columns.